Need help identifying horror movie
I would like some help identifying a horror movie I saw when I was little on late night TV.

Horror/Thriller/Haunted House
1980 - 2008 era
Saw on TV, so could be made-for-TV
English, US

There were a husband and wife who lived in this mansion in the woods, and they were fixing it up. Their son had died (I believe his name was Andy or Ian) and the wife starts to see him around. There was mention of a swamp a couple of times, and then the husband starts to go crazy and tells his wife to stay out of the basement. Afterward, they are playing scrabble with some friends and they hear an animal outside and their dog (golden) is killed, later seen as ghost. Finally, the movie ends with the basement flooding and a corpse chasing the wife around, and an older guy (her dad, I think) pulling her out the basement window. Also, at some point, the lady runs over her husband with a (red?) jeep wrangler. 

It might be the movie Seven Days to Live (2000)

rottentomatoes:

In 1976 a group of English villagers led by cop Carl (Nick Brimble)
  journey to a remote house where they discover a traumatized man and
  the corpse of his wife. Twenty-three years later, the remote house is
  home to Martin (Sean Pertwee), a burned-out novelist, and his American
  wife Ellen (Amanda Plummer), who have settled there following the
  freak death of their young son. Faster than you can say "Heeere's
  Johnny!" weird things start to happen: Ellen becomes convinced that
  she's going to die, while Martin's behavior is increasingly erratic
  and combative. Ellen decides to solve the mystery of her lodgings,
  which locals insist is located on a primeval bog with a somewhat
  unpalatable history.

IMDB

Trying to restart after the devastating death of their son, Ellen
  (Plummer) and Martin (Pertwee) move to a big house out in the country.
  Martin is an author who begins writing his new book, while Ellen who
  is still trying to cope with the loss of her son starts experiencing
  unsettling and eerie things. She begins to receive visual messages
  warning her she has seven days to live. The movie begins to count down
  each day as she receives new messages. Ellen also starts seeing her
  dead son around the house and she begins to investigate the history of
  the house. Built on a marsh where thousands of bodies had been dumped
  the evil that surrounds the house is casting its spell. Martin becomes
  extremely agitated and he directs it at Ellen, as he becomes
  increasingly hostile...The ending scene in the basement with the house sinking 
  into itself and creatures rising from the water in the form of
  shadowed zombies is scary and unnerving. Some suspense is delivered
  with some moderate chills sprinkled throughout.

IMDB - Factual errors 

When Ellen has only three days left, she gets the message while
  playing Scrabble with her friends: twice in a row, she pulls the
  letters "t-h-r-e-e-d-a-y-s" out of the bag, which are nine letters.
  The rules for Scrabble say you can only take a maximum of seven
  letters at once.



Trailer
